# Error column ambiguously defined with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

So I am trying to use inner join for 3 tables and I am getting the already specified error. Here is what I did:

```
SELECT phone 
   INTO v_phone 
FROM PEOPLE 
  INNER JOIN Family ON PEOPLE.ID=FAMILY.ID 
  INNER JOIN PETS ON FAMILY.ID=PETS.ID 
WHERE PETS.ID=:NEW.ID;
```

what is the issue here..

Comment: Is PHONE from FAMILY, PEOPLE or PETS table?  Thats what the error is - it does NOT know which table to get phone from.  Use PEOPLE.PHONE perhaps

Comment: @Grantly wow worked lol thanks. u can post an answer so i can select it as best ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `PHONE` from `FAMILY`, `PEOPLE` or `PETS` table? That is what the error is - it does not know which table to get `phone` from.

**Ambiguous** means that it cannot decide...It could be a choice of many, and it doesn't know which one to choose as it needs more information. Ambiguously defined means the field has too little information (it needs a Table Alias also)

Use `PEOPLE.PHONE` perhaps, depending on which `phone` value you need